# wifi scan results EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED is always false when activity is closed

Tags: android

I observe a very strange behavior: I start Service, in that service I dynamically create a BroadcastReceiver with IntentFilter action= `SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION`. 
When my MainActivity is in `VISIBLE` state, scan results are delivered and updated i.e. `EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED` is `true`. But when I close my MainActivity, scan results are still delivered but `EXTRA_RESULTS_UPDATED` is always `false`. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you encounter this problem, call `startForeground(...)` in Service.